# Object not working with global move

Tags: transforms

I have a problem when i move my object and i set in global.

All object do not move the same way.

[image]

[image]

pls help

Comment: Maybe in the Transform Orientations panel, make sure you've selected Global?

Comment: it looks like you pressed G X X instead of G X. G X will move your objects with the global axis, but if you press G X X (two times X) every object will move along its own (local) x-axis although you set your settings to global.

Comment: Ah yes, thx both of you, i've resolved my problem!